# Unit/integration testing time sensitive C++ code

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

Is there a way to create unit/integration tests that not only test for correctness, but also test that steps were completed within a specific time period?

For example:

```
// MyTestSuite.h
#include <cxxtest/TestSuite.h>
class MyTestSuite : public CxxTest::TestSuite
{
    public:
    void testTimeCriticalFunction(void)
    {
        TS_ASSERT_EQUALS(timeCriticalFunction(), correctValue);

        // timeCriticalFunction() must correctly return within 5 milliseconds
        TS_ASSERT_DID_COMPLETE_WITHIN_MILLISECONDS(timeCriticalFunction(), 5);
    }
}
```

While the example is only one function, it would be ideal if there was a way to chain them together to perform integration testing on a longer sequence such that the test would return true if each step was correct and completed within the specified time as well as the overall group.

Sub-millisecond accuracy is preferred, but typical time requirements are between 5-15 milliseconds.

**UPDATE 1:** The target platform is UNIX (Mac OS X). The precise timing requirements are due to the problem domain (communications).

**UPDATE 2:** Given the comments, assume I'm focusing on *integration* testing.

Comment: Can I recommend that you write a separate test to report on whether the operation is fast enough? Ideally, each unit test would only ever fail for one reason. Otherwise, every time a test goes red, you have to go and figure out which of the n failure reasons caused the failure this time around.

Comment: razlebe: Thank you for your response. You make a valid point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not a good idea to place specific timing requirements such as that at a small granularity. Since you are using OSX you have at most a soft real-time system. (If you have hard real-time requirements a general purpose OS such as OSX is not the answer.) There are a limited number of CPUs / CPU cores available. The OS can somewhat arbitrarily decide to put your thread to sleep, even if your the process / process group is running as super user with a very high priority.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree that using Mac OS X is not an ideal solution since it is not a real-time operating system.

Comment: What you want to do is build performance requirements on your system as a whole. The unit tests should just care about yielding the correct results. When you are testing the system response, you do care about meeting performance requirements. If you meet those goals, fine. You don't have to change a thing. If you don't, you need to find the bottlenecks. A couple of gotchas: #1. Those bottlenecks might not be anywhere in your code. They are instead in the non-deterministic interactions between threads and with the OS. #2 There is not one Mac OSX machine. What if someone is using an old laptop?

Answer (score 0):

If you check in the unit test whether your function finished within certain time, then you are doing it wrong, because that should not be done at the unit testing level (it is more for integration level). That would also increase the time your unit tests are running, and that is bad. Also, it would depend on the platform unit tests are run.

For integration tests, you can check [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Of course the timing is platform-dependent, VJo. One typical reason for having such timing constraints is to achieve guaranteed performance for a real-time application on a very specific platform.

Comment: VJo: Thank you for your response. I share your concern with any testing logic throwing off the timing which could cause issues. I have updated my original question for additional clarity.

Comment: @David You didn't understand what I wrote. Unit tests should be HW independent. You are not going to use the target to execute unit tests, but most likely something more powerful,

Comment: @VJO: Noren is targeting OSX. That said, I agree with you that Noren is muddling the distinction between unit tests and integrated tests.

Answer (score 0):

Unit-tests *should* complete in a determinate (and short) amount of time.  You may be muddling the difference between an integration and unit test a bit.

That being said, your testing framework should solve this for you.  I recommend [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/UnitTest++.html) as being awesome.